# React Redux: отправляю один экшн, улетают все и страница обновляется

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux

может кто-нибудь подсказать, куда рыть?
Я отправляю диспатч с одним экшеном (обратный вызов в классе Converter при вводе в input) а у меня отправляется другой диспатч в классе Api ComponentDidMount. Причем в инпуте событие не срабатывает.
Перечитал кучу статей, ничего не нашел, перебрал пару готовых решений - тоже не увидел ничего нового.
Ниже код:
/container/Root.js:

````
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../configureStore'
import Api from './Api'
import Converter from './Converter'

const store = configureStore()

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {       
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>  
      <Converter />         
        <Api />                  
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

/container/Api.js:
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import getRequestApi from '../actions'
import CreateTable from '../components/CreateTable'


class Api extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch } = this.props
        dispatch(getRequestApi())
    }

    render() {
        const { getload } = this.props
        if (typeof getload !== 'object') {
            return (<div>
                {getload}
            </div>)
        } else {
            const date = new Date(Date.parse(getload.Date)).toLocaleString(),
                previousDate = new Date(Date.parse(getload.PreviousDate)).toLocaleString(),
                timestamp = new Date(Date.parse(getload.Timestamp)).toLocaleString(),
                valute = getload.Valute,
                arrayList = []

            for (const key in valute) {
                if (valute.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    arrayList.push(valute[key])
                }
            }

            const list = arrayList.map((prop) => {
                return <CreateTable key={prop.ID} name={prop.Name} code={prop.CharCode} value={prop.Value} target = {prop.Nominal} />
            })            

            return (<div>

                <h4>Курс на: { date }</h4>
                <h4>Предыдущий срез на: { previousDate }</h4>
                <h5>Отметка времени: { timestamp }</h5>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Код</td><td>Номинал</td><td>Валюта</td><td>Курс (по отношению к рублю)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { list }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>)
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {    
    return {
        getload: store.requestApi.getload
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Api)

/container/Converter.js:
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import setInput from '../actions'
import CreateInputs from '../components/CreateInputs'

class Converter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.changeInput = this.changeInput.bind(this)
        this.changeFirstOption = this.changeFirstOption.bind(this)
        this.changeSecondOption = this.changeSecondOption.bind(this)
        this.buttonsResult = this.buttonsResult.bind(this)
    }

    changeInput(event) {             
        event.preventDefault()
        const {dispatch} = this.props        
        if (!event.target.value.trim()) {
            return
          }         
        dispatch(setInput(event.target.value))
    }

    changeFirstOption() {

    }

    changeSecondOption() {

    }

    buttonsResult() {

    }

    render() {                
        return <div>
            <CreateInputs arrayList = {this.props.arrayList } changeInput={this.changeInput} changeFirstOption={this.changeFirstOption} changeSecondOption={this.changeSecondOption} buttonsResult={this.buttonsResult} />
        </div>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {

    return {
        defaultInput: store.getInput
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Converter)

/components/CreateTable.js:
import React from 'react'

function CreateTable(props) {    
    const name = props.name,
        code = props.code,
        value = props.value,
        target = props.target
    return (<tr>
        <td>{code}</td><td>{target}</td><td>{name}</td><td>{value.toFixed(2)}</td>
    </tr>)
}

export default CreateTable

/components/CreateInputs.js:
import React from 'react'

function CreateOption(props) {
    const name = props.name,
        code = props.code
    return (
        <option value={name}>{code} - {name}</option>
    )
}

function CreateInputs(props) {
    const changeInput = props.changeInput,
        changeFirstOption = props.changeFirstOption,
        changeSecondOption = props.changeSecondOption,
        buttonsResult = props.buttonsResult,       
        arrayList = props.arrayList,
        newArrayList = []
        let input
   return <div>
        <form>
        <input ref={node => (input = node)} type='text' onChange={changeInput}></input>
        </form>
    </div>
}

export default CreateInputs

/actions/index.js:
export const GET_VALUE_API = 'GET_VALUE_API'
export const ERROR_GET_API = 'ERROR_GET_API'
export const SET_INPUT = 'SET_INPUT'

export function beforeRequestApi(load) { 
  return {
    type: GET_VALUE_API,
    load
  }
}

export function errorRequestApi(load) {
  return {
    type: ERROR_GET_API,
    load
  }
}

export default function getRequestApi() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(beforeRequestApi('Загрузка валют...'))
    return fetch('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          return response
        } else {
          let error = new Error(response.statusText)
          error.response = response
          throw error
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (typeof response !== 'object') {
          let error = new Error('Получен недопустимый формат данных')
          error.response = response
          throw error
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        const API = response.json()
        return API
      })
      .then(function (API) {
        dispatch(beforeRequestApi(API))
      })
      .catch(function (text) {
        return dispatch(errorRequestApi('Ошибка в получении данных: ' + text.message))
      });
  }
}


export function setInput(value) { 
  return {
    type: SET_INPUT,
    value
  }
}

/reducers/reducers.js:
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { GET_VALUE_API, ERROR_GET_API, SET_INPUT} from './../actions'

function requestApi(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_VALUE_API:  
      return {...state, getload: action.load }     
    case ERROR_GET_API:
      return action.load           
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function getInput(state = '1', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INPUT:  
      return { ...state, input: action.value } 
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ requestApi, getInput })

export default rootReducer```

Спасибо.
````

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount() срабатывает после re-rendera, поэтому срабатывает dispatch.

```
Изменение store --> re-render Api --> componentDidMount() --> dispatch
```

а store изменяется после каждого нажатия кнопки в input. 
А так как Api подключен к store через connect он каждый раз перерисовывается.

Action можно привязывать к dispatch через connect:
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getRequestApi})(Api)`

Но input не получает state из store. Должно быть что-то типа 
`<input value={state.value} ....`
Поэтом событие возможно доходит до store но мы его не видим в input.

в reducer getInput: `state='1'`   и далее `{ ... state}` - не совсем корректно

тоже в requestApi `state=[]` и далее `{...state}`

____ дополнение:

чтобы не было повторного диспатча в `class Api` дописать:

```
componentDidMount() {        
    if (!this.props.getload) {
      getRequestApi();
    }
}
```

далее:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getRequestApi})(Api)
```

в requestApi `state={}`

в редьюсере:

```
case SET_INPUT: return action.value
```

в классе Converter:

```
<CreateInputs value={this.props.defaultInput} ...
```

в CreateInputs:

```
<input value={props.value} ...
```

Comment: Константин, я правильно понял, что любое изменение store перерисовывает все контейнеры к нему привязанные, даже если в каком-то контейнере ничего не изменилось? И что такое "не совсем корректно" в редьюсерах? За ответы спасибо огромное...

Comment: да изменение store заставляет перерисовывать компонент.   Написал дополнение в ответ. Должно работать

Comment: Константин, ничего не изменилось: мне кажется, потому что в componentDidMount свойство getload иннициализируется сразу же, поэтому оно всегда есть. Ваще не вкуриваю, где тут модульность в redux, если любое изменение store, влечет перерисовку всех контейнеров.

Comment: если проект есть на github могу посмотреть

Comment: Константин, может тебе на почту куда-нибудь я могу скинуть?

Comment: ok: zawzez@gmail.com

Comment: Получил файл? Дичь какая-то творится: роботы почтовые Яндекса и Гугла меня спамят, что письма не доставляются

Comment: С 3-ей попытки через Гугл вроде улетело

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел причину: при монтировании всегда вызывается fetch со строковым значением, соответственно, при перерисовке компонента(обновлении store), fetch всегда вызывается, т.к. react видит произошедшие изменения